# Individual XML files located in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, datasource, context.xml

I'm developing java web application using `tomcat 7` 
I want to have `context.xml` file outside of my war with custom name. I have database resource defined in this file. 
According to [tomcat documentation](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-context#.USyTy6IgdAI), I put `context.xml.default` file in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directrory and I could get database configuration.

Now, I want to rename `context.xml.default` and put custom file name,which matches my contextpath. If I do so, I can't get database configuration anymore and my appliction throws Exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Here is the content o my `context.xml.default` file:

```
<Context
crossContext="true"
reloadable="true" >

 <Resource
    name="jdbc/myDS"
    auth="Container"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    factory="com...encription.util.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
    logAbandoned="true"
    maxActive="30"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="1000"
    password="encryptedPass"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myIP:myPort:FRONT"
    username="username" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be a result of a missing JDBC driver. Try putting the Oracle driver into the `%TOMCAT_HOME%/common/lib` directory.

Another possibility is, that you are missing a web-application specific context.xml (named `<NAME_OF_WEBAPP>.xml`) in `conf/catalina/localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration I used was correct but the problem was that eclipse was using `{catalina_base}/wtpwebapps` directory to deploy web applications.

**I changed wtpwebapps folder with webapps** in server configuration in eclipse and **now everything works correctly.**

Comment: Glad you found the error. But see what I meant about writing complete questions? You never mentioned anything about running in Eclipse...